# Im having a problem about generating QrCode

Tags: jquery, laravel-8

I'm working a project that needs to generate qrcode. but it seems I'm missing something in my codes.

In my controller: (Note:DB::RAW for fullname is working but for qr not.)

```
      if ($query != '') {
      $data = NewModel::where('id_no', '=', $query)
        ->select('reg_code as reg_code',
             DB::RAW("CONCAT(fname,' ',mname,' ',lname,' ',reg_code) as qr"),
             DB::RAW("CONCAT(fname,' ',mname,' ',lname) as fullname"))
    ->first();
       }
```

Then this is how I call the qrcode to:

```
if (count((array)$data) > 0) {
      $data = array(
      \QrCode::generate($data->qr));
       echo json_encode($data);
}
```

In my Model This is how I call my database table:

```
class NewModel extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'Connection';
    protected $table = 'Table_Database';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

This is Edited

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Model, why not use an accessor, like this:

```php
public function getQrCodeAttribute() {
  return "{$this->fname} {$this->mname} {$this->lname} {$this->regcode}";
});
```

Then query your database normally (i.e. don't use `DB::raw()`):

```php
$data = NewModel::where('id_no', '=', $query)->first()
// Note: Replace `$model` and `Model` with the correct name for your Model
```

Then generate your QR Code:

```php
QrCode::generate($data->qr_code);
```

Comment: The `$model = Model::first();` where should I put it to try? In Controller? Or how should I call it properly? Should I put it on model too?

Comment: Wherever you're doing that `DB::raw()` Statement, do `Model::first()` (or however you want to query your table). This is typically done in the Controller. I can't really say more than that since you didn't provide enough code in your original question 

Comment: I can edit it if you need to see my whole codes, I really need to know the answer it's been 7 days I got stucked

Comment: Yeah, you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70514118/edit) and include where you're calling that code and how you're sending it to the view, etc. Sidenote, I won't be able to update my answer today; but I'll check back later.

Comment: All done sir I edited my post

Comment: So yeah; my comment was correct; you simply do `$data = NewModel::where('id_no', '=', $query)->first()` instead of your other query, and the above code should work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will try your given code tomorrow! Thank you.

Comment: I tried the code you given. I already called the function `$data = NewModel::where('id_no', '=', $query)` at the top. That's why I don't know why It's not working

Comment: Your `if()` statement is now wrong maybe? Can just be `if($data){ ... }`. Beyond that, you'll have to better explain what *"it's not working"* means... Do you get any errors? Does the QR code not show up? What is the output of `dd($data)`, etc etc.

Comment: There's no problem with the codes at all, because `DB::RAW("CONCAT(fname,' ',mname,' ',lname) as fullname"))` is working perfectly fine, the thing is when it comes to `QrCode::generate` the qr is not showing at all.

Comment: Well, you're doing `echo json_encode(...)`; why would you expect that to display a QR code and instead a JSON string? If you use proper Laravel logic, like `$qrCode = QrCode::generate($data->qr_code);`, sending that to a `.blade.php` view and displaying it like via `{!! $qrCode !!}` (or maybe `{{ $qrCode }}`; not sure if that generates HTML or something else). Either way; there does appear "to be a problem with your codes" if nothing is being displayed...